# ionic, angular , top position issue

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have the below code that shows a start button. When I change the left parameters, the button moved to the new location. However, it doesn't work for top. Any idea why ?

```
.startbutton{
    position: absolute;
    transition: .5s ease;
    left: 29%; 
    top: 80%;    
}

<ion-view view-title="Dashboard">
  <ion-content>
   <img class="startbutton" src="smiley.gif" />

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: can you provide plunkr ?

Comment: It worked if I uses Fiddle but not in the cordova-ionic-angular app. I did ionic start myapp. Then, I added the following code. This is the problem that occured.  https://jsfiddle.net/JSmithd/7nfe2wb6/

Comment: Anyone knows if this is a bug or something ?